# Reading multiple json files & creating multiple dataframes

Tags: python, azure, for-loop, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to read 2 different json files in 2 different directories in ADLS & create 2 different data frames. Although different dataframes are getting created but its only writing out the latest json file "json2" in this case. I understand the problem that the loop is overwriting instead of appending but not able to manipulate the for loops accordingly. The code is as follows:

```
# Primary storage info
account_name = "account"  # fill in your primary account name
container_name = "json-logs"  # fill in your container name
subscription_id = "subs"
resource_group = "resource-ML" # fill in your resource gropup for ADLS account
workspace_name = "workspace-ML" # fill in your la workspace name

dataframes = ['json1', 'json2']
directories=["test1","test2"]
d = {}

for data in dataframes:
   for direct in directories :
       input_path = f"{direct}"
       adls_path = 
       f"abfss://{container_name}@{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{input_path}"
       account_key = 'key'  # Replace your storage account key
       new_path = input_path
       initialize_storage_account(account_name, account_key)
       pathlist = list_directory_contents(container_name, new_path, "json")
       input_file = pathlist[0].split("/")[-1]
       download_file_from_directory(container_name, new_path, input_file)
       json_normalize("output.json", "out_normalized.json")
       globals()d[data] = pd.read_json('out_normalized.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue by appending the output to a list

```
dataframes = ['json1', 'json2']
directories=["test1","test2"]

# create empty list of dataframes 
listOfDf = []

for data in dataframes:
    for direct in directories :
        input_path = f"{direct}"
           adls_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{input_path}"
        
        account_key = 'KEY'  # Replace your storage account key
        new_path = input_path
        time_start=datetime.now()
        initialize_storage_account(account_name, account_key)
        pathlist = list_directory_contents(container_name, new_path, "json")
        input_file = pathlist[0].split("/")[-1]
        download_file_from_directory(container_name, new_path, input_file)
        json_normalize("output.json", "out_normalized.json")
        df = pd.read_json('out_normalized.json')
        listOfDf.append(df)
```